# Simple timer by angulars js did not work

Tags: angularjs

I try to set up a timer by angular.js.
Could someone tell me why the method2 won`t work?
I had set up an alert to make sure the function had been triggered.
Many thanks.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
<h5>{{ clock }}</h5>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function MyController($scope) {
    alert("start point check");
    var updateClock = function() {
    $scope.clock = new Date();
  };
//method1.  
setInterval(function() {$scope.$apply(updateClock);}, 1000);

//method2.
//setInterval(updateClock, 1000);

updateClock();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should be using $timeout instead of setInterval.

The reason second option does't work is that Angular $digest doesn't identify the changes made via setInterval. It's outside of Angular, hence you need to do a $scope.$apply.

check [this](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) link for better understanding of $apply.